# Prometheus node_exporter metrics - huge spikes in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Our setup includes:

- a few Debian 9.12 nodes with Prometheus node_exporter v. 0.18.1 installed as service
- Prometheus server v. 2.14.0 (on Windows Server 2016) scraping the metrics from nodes
- Grafana visualizing metrics

Basically, our load could be volatile so we'd like to capture details so currently we are scraping metrics every 10 seconds, and display 1-minute rates in Grafana, with queries like that:

```
rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{instance=~'$node',device!~'tap.*|veth.*|br.*|docker.*|virbr*|lo*'}[1m])*8
```

In Grafana we see huge spikes, for network instances with average throughput under 100Mbit/s, spikes exceed hundreds of Gigabits per second which obviously is not exactly technically possible. Same happens for CPU load, CPU wait time, disks iops and other `node_exporter` metrics as well, generally it looks like that, see the dramatic difference between averages and maximums:

[image: network interface spikes]

Apparently this happens because Prometheus seems to 'miss' single points of data, and based on how `rate` works it compares 'last' point with zero to current `node_network_receive_bytes_total` accumulated since last startup and rockets up the output. If we try to switch to `irate` the spikes just jump even higher which seems to prove our guess.

Querying our Prometheus collerting server for datapoints in particular time ranges where our `rate` is having spikes, we do not see any zeroed points, data in 'spiky' time range looks like consecutive increase:

```
node_network_receive_bytes_total{device="ens8",instance="cassandra-xxxxxxxxx0:9100",job="cassandra-xxxxxxxxx"}
3173659836137 @1585311247.489
3173678570634 @1585311257.49
3173696782823 @1585311267.491
3173715943503 @1585311277.492
3173715937480 @1585311277.493
3173731328095 @1585311287.495
3173743034248 @1585311297.502
3173756482486 @1585311307.497
3173775999916 @1585311317.497
3173796096167 @1585311327.498
3173814354877 @1585311337.499
3173833456218 @1585311347.499
3173852345655 @1585311357.501
```

Same on graph:

[image: prometheus graph]

`rate` query `rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{instance="cassandra-xxxxxxxxx0:9100",device!~'tap.*|veth.*|br.*|docker.*|virbr*|lo*'}[1m])*8` is displaying surprisingly different picture in the same time range:

[image: prometheus rate graph]

While Prometheus documentation states that it should extrapolate missing datapoints, as well as certain issues with `rate`/`irate` are [widely recognized](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746), for now we're pretty confused with the above.

Our biggest problem is that the spikes make both visualizing and, more importantly, setting up the limits/alerts impossible.

For now we're only certain that Grafana is out of question and the issue lies within our Prometheus, and the question goes like - have you bumped into something similar, maybe? If yes, how do you deal with that?

If not, maybe you could suggest some further dignostic approach?

Anyway, thank you everybody at least for reading until this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
3173715943503 @1585311277.492
3173715937480 @1585311277.493
```

The values are going backwards, which is treated as a counter reset. This would usually indicate a kernel bug, however given that the values are only one millisecond apart I'm going to guess that what's happening is that you've failed to mention the key detail that this is in fact the merged data from two different Prometheus servers - which isn't going to work as you've discovered.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!

Actually as far as I'm concerned we have only one Prometheus server scraping metrics from all hosts, at least this is what all team agrees on.

I'll have to check other spikes if they have the same pattern.

Comment: That's not from a single scraper one way or the other. The increasing milliseconds timestamps is also odd, but that could be due to the lack of accuracy in the Windows clock APIs.